# UEFI shell mode with no colon key

Tags: keyboard, shell, keyboard-layout, uefi

I have a newly built PC with a UEFI-enabled motherboard and I'm having trouble getting my DVD drive to boot into UEFI mode so I opted to boot into UEFI Shell to manually start the DVD in UEFI mode. The problem I'm running into from here is that I have an international keyboard that has fewer buttons than the normal US keyboard layout but the shell treats it as a standard US keyboard layout, and after testing all the keys I've found that none of them operates as a colon (:) key. This key seems absolutely required to run the UEFI shell commands to select the device (i.e. `fs0:` or `blk3:`).

Is there any other alias to this command to select a device without the colon? Is there any way to change the keyboard layout in UEFI shell to match my keyboard (which does in fact have a colon key)?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously a little late, but in my case it is `shift + ö`.

Answer (score 1):

UEFI Shell tip:

It is important to be able to type a colon for file management purposes.  The only answer I've found is to use an older wired keyboard.   Wired windows keyboards, wireless keyboards don't work.   The only solution for me was to use the full size wired Apple keyboard.